# Are question bookmarks anonymous, like votes?

Tags: support, questions

**Are bookmarks on questions anonymous?**

In many questions, answers already state that upvotes and downvotes are 100% anonymous and can't be seen, that moderators/developers can't even see them. Questions that are beneficial that you need help with too you bookmark when you see that is has a answer or it has a bounty and is expecting an answer.

Are bookmarks anonymous, or can you see them on the activity?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “bookmarking” and “following” a question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15152/4797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are bookmarks anonymous?

**No**. Your bookmarks are always visible on your profile. They are on the main 'top activity' page:

https://arqade.com/users/current?tab=topactivity

[image: Bookmarks section]

In addition, there's an entire page/tab for them:

https://arqade.com/users/current?tab=bookmarks

[image: Bookmarks page]

These pages are publicly available, even to anonymous/not logged in users. Try opening my bookmarks page in a private window:

https://arqade.com/users/28182/robotnik?tab=bookmarks

Comment: Robotnik will always want to know if a corpse is safe to eat ;)

Comment: The only two pages that are privately yours are "Responses" and "Votes". All other actions and things you own are public.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf hahaha. Still the best 'out of context' question on this site :)